# Unexplainable behaviour of c array in OpenCL

Tags: arrays, opencl, c99

I ran across an interesting problem: If I define an array inside my function, it works fine, however if I define the same array outside the function and pass it as a parameter, the array behaves differently.

```
void main()
{
     unsigned short arr[8] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
     fun([...], arr);
}

void fun([...], unsigned short * arr, [...])
{
        [...]
    unsigned short fun_arr[8] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        if(arr[i] != fun_arr[i])
            printf("Not the same"); 

    //until here it works. the arrays are the same, I get no output, as expected

    //this works just fine aswell
    float f = some_float_array[fun_arr[0]];
    //this works aswell
    unsigned short index_from_arr = arr[0];
    //this doesnt. The program crashes (-9999, which isnt an actual OpenCL error)
    float f = some_float_array[arr[0]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Array arguments to functions are just pointers. And pointers in OpenCL always refer to a specific *memory space*. Unfortunately, there's a default, which is `global` so that's where your inner function `fun` is looking. The array you've declared in main and are passing to `fun()` is in the `private` address space. For some reason, many (most? all?) implementations don't even generate warnings in this case, so you have to constantly be on guard for this mistake.

The solution is to annotate your function argument with `private`. From personal experience, I recommend stating the address space of **all** pointers in OpenCL explicitly.

**Update:**

Please note also that as you're using pointers to `unsigned short`, word/byte addressing limitations may apply unless your implementation explicitly does not have those limitations. See also https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_byte_addressable_store.html

If in doubt, switch to `unsigned int` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Im still getting the same error. Also it could not have been the cause since accessing it in the for loop and assining another variable to an element in the array works...

Comment: Are you initialising `arr` anywhere? Uninitialised variables are undefined behaviour regardless. (Please update to a minimal complete example that illustrates the problem - "[...]" is not helpful, as that might be where your problem lies, and we have to make assumptions.) Also good to know: platform and OpenCL implementation.

Comment: Also, note https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_byte_addressable_store.html

Comment: I edited my code. [...] refers to code that's not important. I just thought, i would leave that there. cl_khr_byte_addressable_store didn't change anything, also my kernel uses short and char types in other places, where they work fine.

Comment: The code might not seem important, but: if you remove it, does the problem still occur? The byte addressing restriction isn't as simple as "don't use short and char types" - it's about byte- and short-sized stores via pointers and arrays. So scalar variables aren't affected. Also, undefined behaviour can still be "it works in some cases."